# A confusion in Bernoulli equation solution

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, bernoulli-polynomials

I have a bernoulli equation with its proper and correct solution written step by step. The issue is that it contains a line that is transformed to the 2nd line which I was unable to understand how it is transformed. Here is the image of question and its solution, the problematic lines are highlighted in the image.

[Click here to see the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/629X5.png)

Please tell me how this transformation is done. thanks

Comment: how it is transformed to dv/dx + 2v = -2?? I calculated my answer is: dv/dx+2v = 0

Answer (score 1):

The two lines are independent. One shows how the derivative is obtained and the next is the substitution.

Comment: how it is transformed? I substituted but it is not that way. From where "-2" came in its RHS?

Comment: @YasirMalik : They are taking the derivative of $v=y^{-2}$ to get $v'=-2y^{-3}y'$ and from there $y^{-3}y'=-\frac12v'$.

Comment: how it is transformed to dv/dx + 2v = -2??
I calculated my answer is: dv/dx+2v = 0

Comment: For the record, I had other things to do - language like thst will not be tolerated here.

Answer (score 0):

The first line:
You have y=v^-1/2, so

dy/dx = -1/2  V^-3/2  dv/dx

V^3/2 dy/dx =-1/2dv/dx

y^-3 dy/dx = -1/2 dv/dx

As for the second line:

y^-3 dy/dx = -1/2 dv/dx

dv/dx = -2y^-3 dy/dx =-2 (1+ y^-2) = -2-2y^-2 = -2-2v

So the equation is reduced to dv/dx + 2v = 2